# Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED. Error when trying to save the feature maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I want to save the feature maps which are generated when i give an image as input to VGG16. But I'm getting this error. Please help me :)

```
2020-05-03 19:31:42.361061: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-05-03 19:31:43.634465: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-05-03 19:31:43.638077: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-05-03 19:31:43.641090: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[{{node block1_conv1/convolution}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sreec\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\Project\Test\Test.py", line 44, in <module>
    feature_maps = model.predict(img)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1462, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 324, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3727, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1551, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1591, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[node block1_conv1/convolution (defined at D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_458]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What is throwing that error? We need more information than this. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Nevermind. I actually found that my VRAM wasn't enough to train my model

Answer (score 1):

You can try GPU memory resources management by [limiting GPU memory growth](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth).

It can be done by calling `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`, which attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory as needed for the runtime allocations: it starts out allocating very little memory, and as the program gets run and more GPU memory is needed, we extend the GPU memory region allocated to the TensorFlow process.

To turn on memory growth for a specific GPU, use the following code prior to allocating any tensors or executing any ops.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```